# Mongoose aggregate with $lookup from multiple collections returning empty set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections:

1. users
2. companies
3. stores

Users and stores have object refs to companies.

**users:**
`company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'}`

**stores:**
`parentCompany: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company'}`

I am trying a simple aggregate on companies and want to have all users and stores for a given company.

```
companyModel.aggregate(
        [
            { $match: { _id: 'companyidhere123445' } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'stores',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'parentCompany',
                    as: 'stores',
                }
            },
            { $unwind: '$stores' },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'users',
                    localField: '_id',
                    foreignField: 'company',
                    as: 'users',
                }
            },
            { $unwind: '$users' },
        ]);
```

I am getting an empty array. (Yes, I tested the id match, model.find returns company for that same id, yes separately users and stores match the id on `company` and `parentCompany` fields, respectively. I already checked the possible duplicates and I can't figure what I am doing differently, but my aggregate is returning empty. Tested the same query from mongoose and in mongo shell. No errors, no warnings.)

Comment: Are u matching the _id as ObjectId or string format?

Comment: did you try debugging by removing the stages. You can use also [mongodb compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) to build better aggregates

Comment: I did remove stages, same result until I'm down to company. @fractal397: No, id is ObjectId, as I mentioned, same id returns the company, or users or stores separately just fine.

Comment: @fractal397 : You were right with your suspicion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! (One of those days I guess!)

The id is in the req.params, even though this works fine for queries like findOne or findById, it doesn't for aggregate, so I had to recast it as mongoose object id before using in the match:

```
const matchId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);
```

then:

```
{ $match: { _id: matchId } },
```

and voila!  (Where do I get that gif of banging head against the keyboard?)